# Making http request from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

I am trying to implement [Message API](http://docs.3cinteractive.com/Message_API)

I am not sure how I will be calling this from code-behind  and in their snippet it says:

```
https://platform.3cinteractive.com/api/send_message.php 

POST
username=aRDSe3vcaMzh06YrMcxcQw==&password=1BSvQc6lpNlnp4ufWgRLPHNJ7RMrL8CcaWCzL1Vtw+Y=&phone_number=+11234567890&trigger_id=1105&message=howdy
```

Comment: Are you looking for instructions on how to wrap up an HTTPWebRequest()?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) class below or use a library like [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) for more control or your HTTP request:

```
// Create a request for the URL.        
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create ("http://www.contoso.com/default.html");
// If required by the server, set the credentials.
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
// Get the response.
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse ();
// Display the status.
Console.WriteLine (response.StatusDescription);
// Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
// Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);
// Read the content.
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();
// Display the content.
Console.WriteLine (responseFromServer);
// Cleanup the streams and the response.
reader.Close ();
dataStream.Close ();
response.Close ();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a WebRequest and do an HTTP POST. See this article entitled [How to: Send Data Using the WebRequest Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx).